# How can I set tramp-histfile-override using tramp-connection-properties?

Tags: tramp, ssh

I'm trying to set a different tramp history file override based on connection-specific rules. My attempts have been along the line of:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
             (list (regexp-quote "/ssh:myremotehost:")
                   "histfile-override"
                   ".tramp_history3"))
```

But it's not working.

I think it might be because `tramp-histfile-override` isn't a pre-defined method-specific parameter to any methods in my `tramp-methods` (eg ssh). Therefore `tramp-connection-properties` can't be used to override this variable in this case?

Is there a way of customizing `tramp-histfile-override` on a per-connection basis?

Emacs version: 26.1
Tramp version: 2.3.3.26.1
OS version: OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tramp-histfile-override` is an ordinary user option. It is not prepared for `tramp-connection-properties` or connection-local variables.

If you want to get this changed, you might write a bug report.